# Failed to Start Apache tomcat from eclipse juno in linux at port 80

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jakarta-ee

At the window platform I have run tomcat from eclipse juno. But at linux I face this problem

When I run web project from eclipse I got this error message, while from command line I can able to run tomcat.

> Error Message is - Port 80 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost
>   is already in use. The server may already be running in another
>   process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this
>   server you will need to stop the other process or change the port
>   number(s).

I already check my port using nmap and other command

The main point is that when I run tomcat from command line then it start, but when I start this from eclipse I got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check again whether the port is indeed in use. I believe that you have apache web server (httpd) that is taking the port.

Second, on linux only processes running under root user can use lower ports (under 100). Probably when you run tomcat from command line you run it as root (e.g. using sudo), however when you are running it from eclipse it is running under your user.

The solution is:
for development use other port. E.g `8080`.

For production:
use special user account (not root) to run tomcat. E.g. user named `tomcat`. Configure it to listen to port 8080. Run apache web server (httpd) under root user configured to listen to port 8080 and configured to be connected to tomcat using mod_jk. This is most secure and reliable commonly used configuration.

Comment: i have change apache webserver port from 80 to 90 , you are right i run tomcat as a root user, is it possible to run tomcat from eclipse at port 80 , required by application

Answer (score 0):

I believe linux comes with a apache server, which may be running on port 80. So when you try to run the tomcat on the same port, it is complaining port already in use. To find out if apache is installed you can use the rpm command. I believe it is rpm -qa will tell you all packages installed. Now as far as the directory for apache files it is normally 
/var/www/htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

After starting Tomcat from the command line you also stopped it? Because if Tomcat is still running from the command line you get this error while trying to start it again out of eclipse.

Is it right that you run your Tomcat on Port 80? This wont work in an Linux environment, because Linux comes up with an Apache Webserver listening on Port 80.